# exporting access table from one access database to a new access database

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

Good afternoon,
I need to export table from one database to a new database in the specific folder. Table name is "Detail Report". New database's name needs to be "Detail Report" too. I have been trying multiple codes, but nothing is working.

The most recent code I am trying to use is:

```vb
DoCmd.TransferDatabase , acExport, acTable, "Detail Report", "Y:\Charter\working\new folder\"Detail Report.accd", False
```

Please help and let me know what I am missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the correct syntax:

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase  acExport, "Microsoft Access", "Y:\Charter\working\new folder\Detail Report.accd", acTable, "Detail Report", "Detail Report", False
```

And the target database must exist.

To create a database: [DBEngine.CreateDatabase Method (DAO)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835033(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your help. It worked. Just one question: there is no way to write a code that will create that detail report database? It has to exist?

Comment: Yes, but you can create it. See edited answer, please.